# clear the touch uiimageview while clicking next button

Tags: ios

How to remove filled colors?

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    alphabetsStoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:
        @"write a.png", @"write b.png", @"write c.png",
        @"write d.png", @"write e.png", @"write f.png", 
        @"write g.png", @"write h.png", @"write i.png",
        @"write j.png", @"write k.png", @"write l.png",
        @"write m.png", @"write n.png", @"write o.png",
        @"write p.png", @"write q.png", @"write r.png",
        @"write s.png", @"write t.png", @"write u.png",
        @"write v.png", @"write w.png", @"write x.png",
        @"write y.png", @"write z.png", nil];

    _homePopupView.hidden=true;

    [self names];
}

-(void)names{
     _voice = @"en-US";
    _speed = .25f;
    if(count>= alphabetsStoreArray.count)
    {
        printf("%d", count);
        NSLog(@"finished");
        [_alphabetChangeImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [_alphabetBackgroundImageView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    else if(count<alphabetsStoreArray.count||count<-1)
    {
        items = [[alphabetsStoreArray objectAtIndex:count] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

        NSString *tempString = [items objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *tempArray = [tempString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        speechString1 = [tempArray objectAtIndex:1];

        if ([_synthesizer isPaused]) {
            [_synthesizer continueSpeaking];
        }

        else{
            [self speakText:speechString1];
              [self textToSpeechAction:alphabetsStoreArray :count :_alphabetBackgroundImageView  :_alphabetChangeImageView :isMicPresent];


        }
    }
}

-(void)textToSpeechAction:(NSMutableArray *)imageStoreArray :(int)counter :(UIImageView *)imageChangeImageView :(UIImageView *)spekerOrMic :(BOOL)isMicPresent
{
    _alphabetChangeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageStoreArray objectAtIndex:counter]];
}

- (void)speakText:(NSString*)text{
    if(_synthesizer == nil)
        _synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    _synthesizer.delegate = self;

    AVSpeechUtterance *utterence = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:text];
    utterence.rate = _speed;

    AVSpeechSynthesisVoice *voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:_voice];
    [utterence setVoice:voice];

    [_synthesizer speakUtterance:utterence];
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event

{
    // Initialize a new path for the user gesture
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:_alphabetBackgroundImageView];

    if((location.x > 50 && location.x < _alphabetBackgroundImageView.frame.size.width-50) && (location.y > 50 && location.y < _alphabetBackgroundImageView.frame.size.height-50))

    {
       lineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        lineImageView.center = location;
        lineImageView.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
        [_alphabetBackgroundImageView addSubview:lineImageView];
    }
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event

{
    // Add new points to the path
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:_alphabetBackgroundImageView];

    if((location.x > 50 && location.x <_alphabetBackgroundImageView.frame.size.width-50) && (location.y > 50 && location.y < _alphabetBackgroundImageView.frame.size.height-50))

    {
       lineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

        lineImageView.center = location;
        lineImageView.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
        [_alphabetBackgroundImageView addSubview:lineImageView];
    }
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet* touchesForTargetView = [event touchesForView:self.alphabetBackgroundImageView];

    if (touchesForTargetView.allObjects.count != 0) {
        NSLog(@"yes");
        // touch was at target view
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"no");
        // touch  was somewhere else
    }
}

- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didStartSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance{
    [self buttonoperation];
    _next.enabled = YES;
}

- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didCancelSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance{

    // Enable/Disable buttons accordingly
    [self buttonoperation];

    _retry.enabled = NO;
    count +=1;
    [self names];
}

- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:(NSRange)characterRange utterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance{

    // Get the text
    NSString *text = [utterance speechString];

    // apply attribute
    NSMutableAttributedString * all = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
    [all addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:characterRange];

    // set the attributed text to textView
    [_tvTextToSpeak setAttributedText:all];
}

- (IBAction)nextAction:(id)sender {
    if ([_synthesizer isSpeaking]) {
        [_synthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
        [self buttonoperation];
        _next.enabled = NO;
        [_tvTextToSpeak setText:speechString1];
    }
    count++;
    [self names];
}
```

here I have two imageview 1.aplhabetbackground 2.alphabetchangingbackground.

So according to my code when next button clicked the 2nd data from alphabet store array its image will display in the imageview. And so clicking on the next button it will shows next  image and so.

here I have used touch event in alphabet background .So when image is display i can touch on the screen and filled with the selected colour.

But I need while clicking the next button the filled color should remove from it. How to do

Comment: how to clear the subview

Comment: how could the touched image view

Comment: `lineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];` you're making a new instance everytime? I guess it should be a global variable and initialize just once. Well `lineImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` will remove its color.